# What is the historical background of "Hyperbolic Laplacian" $\Delta_{k}=-y^2(\partial^2_{x}+\partial^2_{y})+iky(\partial_{x}+\partial_{y})$?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, modular-forms, laplacian

I am interested in harmonic Maass form. I would like to know the historical background of hyperbolic Laplacian
$$
\Delta_{k}=-y^2(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2})+iky(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}).
$$
I know that $\Delta_{0}$ is the same as the Laplace-Beltrami operator of the hyperbolic plane $\{x+iy \mid x,y \in \mathbb{R},\ y>0\}$ with metric $ds^2 = \frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}.$ Then, what is the second term $iky(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y})$? In what kind of study was $\Delta_{k}$ discoverd?

I know that Maass form is named after Hans Maass. But I do not know much about his work because I cannot read German well. I read "On two geometric theta lifts" (Bruinier and Funke), but I could not understand why $\Delta_{k}$ was introdued in that paper.

Please tell me the background of $\Delta_{k}$ or some good reference about it.

Comment: Check Bump's Automorphic Forms and Representations